# how to access a single array throughout the project java

Tags: java, arraylist, dns, singleton, server

I'm making a program with multiple servers and clients controlled by a central server, like DNS, the operation of the program is:

1. The central server starts named `Servidor_Borda`
2. The other server connects in `Servidor_Borda` and your IP is save in a arraylist.
3. When a client wants to connect he needs go to Servidor_Borda and receive a valid IP to connect.

My problem is when the client asks for IP to connect the `ArrayList` is always empty, I can't do a unique array.

```
public class Servidor_Borda {

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
    int porta = 4004;
    try{
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(porta);
        Socket socketConexao;
        System.out.print("Aguardando conexões...\n");
    while(true){
        socketConexao = serverSocket.accept();
        String ip = socketConexao.getInetAddress().getHostAddress();            
        listaAtivos.getInstance().addServidor(ip);
        TrataConexao trataC = new TrataConexao(socketConexao);
        new Thread(trataC).start();
    }    
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.print("Porta em uso!");
    }      
}
}


public class listaAtivos {

private static listaAtivos singleton = null;
private ArrayList<String> servidoresConectados;

private listaAtivos(){
    servidoresConectados = new ArrayList<>();
}

public static listaAtivos getInstance(){
    if(singleton==null){
        singleton = new listaAtivos();
    }
    return singleton;
}

public void addServidor(String ip){
    servidoresConectados.add(ip);
    exibeAtivos();
}

public String escolheServidor(){
    int tam = servidoresConectados.size();
    if(tam != 0){
        for(int i=0;i<tam;i++){
            String ip = servidoresConectados.get(i);
            return ip;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
}


public class Cliente {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        int porta = 4008;        
        String ip = listaAtivos.getInstance().escolheServidor();
        Socket s = new Socket(ip,porta);
    }  

}
```

Comment: When you have two separate programs running, e.g one client and one server, none of them can directly access the data of the other one. If your server knows the addresses, the client has no way of accessing the server's `listaAtivos`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server is running on 4004 port but you are trying to access the connection from client in 4008. Therefore the connection is never being done and so `serverSocket.accept()` is getting blocked and the it waits forever being blocking in nature. Please find the link below for details.

http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#accept%28%29

But the exact behavior is not possible as you are running the client program from another console and it will have no impact in the singleton created by the server. It will always create a new instance of the listaAtivos with null.